# Написать функцию, которая из полной фамилии имени и отчества создает фамилию и инициалы (Использовать string) c++

Tags: c++, строки

````
 ```string PIB(string fullName){
    //...
}
int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    cout << PIB("Иваненко Петр Степанович") << endl;  //Иваненко П.С.
    cout << PIB(" Иваненко Петр Степанович") << endl; //Иваненко П.С.
    cout << PIB("Иваненко Петр Степанович ")<< endl;  //Иваненко П.С.
    cout << PIB(" Иваненко Петр Степанович ")<< endl; //Иваненко П.С.
} ```
````

Comment: А есть какие-то гарантии? Что, например, фамилия — одно слово? Или имя? Типа, не будет ли Бендер Задунайский Остап Сулейман Берта Мария? :)

Answer (score 2):

Если гарантируется три слова в определенном порядке — то можно, например, так...

```
string PIB(const string& fullName)
{
    istringstream is(fullName);
    string res, tmp;
    is >> res >> tmp;
    res = res + " " + tmp[0] + ".";
    is >> tmp;
    res = res + tmp[0] + ".";
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Можете скинуть полный код со всема библиотеками? у меня не работает код я думаю дело в библиотеке

Comment: `<string>` и `<sstream>`.